# Differences in the ways to running Python scripts

Tags: python, django

I have a very simple Python question, with examples using Django. When running a Python script, do I always have to precede the script filename with the *python* command?

In the Django tutorial I am following, some commands are as follows:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

However, other are like this:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Why does the top one not need the *python* command?

Alternatively, if my system knows that all Python scripts are to be executed by my python interpreter, why does the bottom one need the *python* command at all?

Comment: I believe `django-admin.py` should have a shebang at the top that says to implicitly run the python interpreter.

Comment: @austin That's correct, but `manage.py` is also auto-generated with the shebang.  It does't have executable flag set, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in a combination of two things:

1. The [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), the first line of a file.
2. The permissions on the file, namely whether the [executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_%28Unix%29) flag is set or not.

Consider the first line of `django-manage.py`.  On my system it is at `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py` and the first line is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

And the permissions on the file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 127 Jan  9 13:38 /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
```

The shebang tells my OS that I want to execute the file with the interpreter at `/usr/bin/python2.7`.  The `x` characters in the permissions say that it is an executable file.  I don't need to specify `python` beforehand, because the OS can figure out that stuff automatically from the above pieces of information.

---

Now for a freshly created `manage.py`, which I made by running `django-admin.py startproject mysite`, it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And the permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 wim wim 249 Feb 17 17:33 manage.py
```

The shebang indicates to use whatever python interpreter my `env` is pointing at, so that part is in place already.  But the file lacks executable permissions, so just running `./manage.py` won't work (yet).

I can make it behave the same as `django-manage.py` by explicitly setting the executable flag using `chmod +x manage.py`.  After that, you should see the `x` flags set when you do `ls -l` in the directory, and you should be able to run the file without specifying `python` beforehand.

*Note:* you *do* still have to use `./manage.py` not just `manage.py`, this discrepancy is because `django-admin.py` lives in `/usr/local/bin/` which is contained in [`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) whereas the `manage.py` file likely doesn't.  So we explicitly specify the path at the shell, where `.` refers to the current directory.

Comment: Probably worth being explicit that the given `manage.py` would be executable if-and-only-if given `+x` bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the script executable by using `chmod +x script.py`, but you need the shebang line, usually `#!/usr/bin/python`
If you are using a script heavily on a unix-based maching (mac,linux) making an alias can be useful:
`alias command="python path/to/script.py"`

Comment: It might be better to suggest functions than aliases -- there's no practical difference in this specific case, but there are a great many situations where aliases aren't powerful enough to be applicable (anywhere some kind of logic needs to happen during expansion, or where arguments would go anywhere but the end, etc). `mycommand() { python /path/to/myscript "$@"; }`