# Is there any difference in using: python manage.py [something] or ./manage.py [something]

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering if there any difference  in using of following constructions?
 python manage.py [something] 
or 
 ./manage.py [something]

Maybe there is preffered command for one statement like runserver and another for syncdb for example?

Comment: possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21835424/674039

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When invoking Python script via:

```
./script.py
```

.. it uses the Python interpreter [defined in the script head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128669/python-script-header). This should point to the Python interpreter defined in the environment, though sometimes (rarely) this might not be the case if the script author has not put in a proper head.

When invoking Python script via:

```
python script.py
```

... it uses Python interprefer from `PATH` environment variable, usually pointing to [the currently activated virtualenv](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/). This is what you get if you run `which python` command.

In most situations the Python interpreter should be the same.

You could also do:

```
/usr/bin/python script.py
```

... to force the usage of system-wide Python installation.

EDIT: Clarified the script head part.

Comment: when we use `#!/usr/bin/env python` they are usually the same thing

Comment: If you put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the script, you get the best of both worlds, as env uses the search path to find the Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, clarified the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no huge difference, except 2 things :

1. You have to give the execute right to your file manage.py (chmod +x manage.py)
2. The file has to contain for example `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top.